# Microsoft Graph SDK ExtensionName weird property

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I add AdditionalData to Event.Extensions:

```
Extensions = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.Extension>
{
    new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Extension()
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "extensionName", "Samtalsbokning" },
            { "itemId", itemId },
            { "siteId", siteId },
            { "type", "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension" }
        },
        OdataType = "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    }
}.ToList()
```

When I read an event, it is in property beside AdditionalData. Copied from immediate window:

```
item.Extensions[0]
{Microsoft.Graph.Models.OpenTypeExtension}
    AdditionalData: Count = 3
    BackingStore: {Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Store.InMemoryBackingStore}
    ExtensionName: "Samtalsbokning"
    Id: "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Samtalsbokning"
    OdataType: "#microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension"
item.Extensions[0].ExtensionName
error CS1061: 'Extension' does not contain a definition for 'ExtensionName' and no accessible extension method 'ExtensionName' accepting a first argument of type 'Extension' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Why it isnt in AdditionalData? Why I cannot select it with .ExtensionName?

My workaround:

```
class Extension
{
    public string ExtensionName { get; set; }
}
```

and read it after parsing: (extension.ExtensionName)

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exItem);
Extension extension = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Extension>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Graph.Models.OpenTypeExtension` is inherited from `Microsoft.Graph.Models.Extensions`, so try to filter items based on the type

```
var openTypeExtensions = item.Extensions.OfType<OpenTypeExtension>();
```